# Images added to div are not affected by the scrollbar

Tags: javascript, html, image, scrollbar, overflow

I have an empty div with a scrollbar:

```
<div id="figure1" style="width:1000px; height:300px; overflow:scroll;"></div>
```

And using javascript I am adding images into the div:

```
function add_img(imgID, src, x, y, height, width){
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.setAttribute('id', imgID);
    img.setAttribute('src', src);
    img.style.left = x;
    img.style.top = y;
    img.style.width = width;
    img.style.height = height;
    img.style.position = 'absolute';
    document.getElementById('figure1').appendChild(img);
}
```

When I add a new image outside of the 1000x300px box, I want that image to only be visible when you use the scrollbar.

Instead, the images which lie outside of the box overflow beyond the edges of figure1. The scrollbar doesn't do anything.

How can I stop the images from overflowing?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't get it: You're adding the image as a child of figure1, but it should appear outside of figure1? Sounds somewhat like a z-index issue, but I'n not sure what to understand what you're trying to do

Comment: Hi, sorry for the confusion. Figure1 is a 1000x300px box. If I add an image to say x=2000 y=100, I want the image to be visible within the div boundaries but only when you scroll the div 1000px to the right. Instead, the image appears 1000px to the right of the div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two issue - first you need to add `+ "px"` to your dimensions (at least if you use integer type parameters like I did).

The other thing would be not to use `position = "absolute"`. For example `position = "relative"` seems to do the trick. (If you like, have a further read on the layout options in CSS, good luck)

https://jsfiddle.net/xpsu9usw/

Comment: Hi, thank you so much it works now! Although I did not make it clear, I wanted to be able to stack images on top of each other but using position:relative does not allow that. As a workaround, I added position:relative to the div and position:absolute to the images.